# Is there a way to get the current Windows login username using Html, php, etc.?

Tags: php, windows

I have had this problem for some time.
I have set up a Windows IIS. But I would like to read the Windows username of the person who calls the page.

On other sites there is as solution: $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'];
But this did not work for me. I guess because the user who calls the page is an anonymous user.
As an idea to solve this, I turned on authentication in Windows IIS Manager.
[IIS-Manager Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RvSg.png)

But that didn't solve my problem either.
My question now is: Does anyone have an idea how I could solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899643/how-to-read-windows-logged-in-username-with-php-iis gives some alternative values which may give the information you are after.

Comment: $_SERVER['LOGON_USER']
$_SERVER['AUTH_USER']
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_LOGON_USER']
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_AUTH_USER']

I tried thoose to but it didn't work either :c

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to do this.

Since you are using Windows IIS you should be able to use this `exec()` command.

```php
exec("wmic /node:$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR] COMPUTERSYSTEM Get UserName", $user);
echo($user[1]);
```

I got [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31966537/12437108) from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31953220/12437108) here.

I tested it out on my windows machine locally, and it worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Rather than just copy an answer from another question, you should post a comment that this is a duplicate.

Comment: Hello Tim,
Thanks for your answer.

I now wrote in my php file:
`
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
 <h5> <?php 
   exec("wmic /node:$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR] COMPUTERSYSTEM Get UserName", $user);
   echo($user[1]); 
   ?> 
 </h5>
</body>
</html>
`

But when I load the page, nothing shows up :c

Answer (score 0):

for me worked:

```
<?php
$username = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);     
echo($username);
?>
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.